# Why does the scalar field have the wrong sign mass term in its Lagrangian to spontaneously break?

Tags: higgs, symmetry-breaking

In a class, the professor said that there are "some" reasons why the scalar field should have had wrong sign mass term in its lagrangian.
What are those reasons?

(In undergraduate textbook, Griffiths only says 'God's computer returns an error message'. The professor also mentioned tachyonic mass which is imaginary. Is it relevant here?)

## edit

I am dealing with following Lagrangian:
$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}[(\partial_\mu-\frac{iq}{\hbar c}A_\mu)\phi^*]
[(\partial_\mu+\frac{iq}{\hbar c}A_\mu)\phi] + \frac{1}{2}\mu^2 (\phi^*\phi)-\frac{1}{4}\lambda^2(\phi^*\phi)^2-\frac{1}{16\pi}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}
$

and the reason why I'm saying it has wrong sign mass is that it($+\frac{1}{2}\mu^2(\phi^*\phi$)) is opposite to the sign in usual scalar QED.

(I edited Lagrangian because I accidently left out $\phi^4$term.)

Comment: You don't give much of a context though: what minus sign and why would you think it is "wrong"?

Comment: The Higgs field, which is a type of scalar field,  gives the wrong sign for the mass term. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @SuperCiocia Yes. That's what I'm saying. I apologise for the absence of the Lagrangian in the original question.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Thank you for comment and I edited the passage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong sign means that the minimum of the potential is not at $\phi = 0$. If the energy is bounded from below, you must have another term in the potential that has the right (positive) sign and that dominates at large values of $\phi$, for instance $\phi^4$.

For simplicity, assume that you have a potential of the form $-m^2 \phi^2 + \lambda \phi ^4$. Then you can show that the minimum of the energy is obtained for a field $\phi$ that takes some constant value $\phi_0 \neq 0$. In the initial potential, you had a symmetry $\phi \rightarrow - \phi$ because only even powers are present. But this symmetry is lost in the vacuum where $\phi = \phi_0$. When there is a symmetry in an equation that is lost in the solutions of this equation, physicists say that there is spontaneous symmetry breaking.

In summary, you see that the "wrong" sign in front of the mass term, that signals a local instability, has triggered a spontaneous breaking of some symmetry.

If you know about the Higgs mechanism in the Standard Model, something similar happens.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood from your post that it is the nature of Higgs field that has minimum potential at nonzero field value and this nature drives SSB and Higgs mechanism, is it correct? Then the scalar QED I wrote down on the passage with "not wrong" mass term is not the nature of higgs field? (if so who is this scalar qed field?)

Comment: The term $(\phi^* \phi)^2$ is your Lagrangian is not a mass term, it is quadratic!

Comment: Ah.. it's my mistake... I shall edit my passage!

Comment: For the rest of your question, I don't understand what you mean by "nature" of Higgs field. In the standard model, the Higgs field has the wrong sign in front of the mass term, so it acquires a non-vanishing vacuum expectation value. This leads to spontaneous breaking of gauge invariance, and gives a mass to the gauge bosons (via eating a Goldstone boson).

Comment: Thanks and apologise for many comments... but pretty many times I have seen scalar QED(the $phi^4$ theory with the negative mass term in Lagrangian).  It seems like higgs field is different from the field of scalar qed... I used "the nature" for that reason, which now I think is not rigorous terminology.

Comment: Scalar QED means that you have a $U(1)$ gauge theory with one scalar field which is charged under this $U(1)$. In the standard model, the Higgs mechanism takes place in an $SU(2)$ gauge theory, so this is not the same think. If you want, scalar QED is a toy model.

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously broken scalar theories have a $\phi^4$ term that requires a negative $\phi^2$ (mass) term in order to give the central hump of the characteristic Mexican hat potential. Without that hump, spontaneous symmetry breaking would not occur.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm not asking how it ssb but why the potential has negative(rather than positive) mass term..!