# Taylor expansion of some Lagrangian (Understanding the Blundell's Quantum field theory, Example 26.5)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential, field-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking

I am reading the Lancaster, Blundell's Quantum field theory for the Gifted Amateur, p.243, Example 26.5 and I can't understand some sentences and I don't know how to expand some Lagrangian.

I am a mathematician studying quantum field theory and want to understand each sentence completely and rigorously. Please understand although this question seems a bit basic and easy :)

In the example, after introducing polar coordinate $\psi(x)=\rho(x)e^{i\theta(x)}$ and $C_{\mu}
:=A_{\mu}+\frac{1}{q}\partial_{\mu}\theta$ , he asserted that we can rewrite the Lagrangian (26.15) (his book p.242) in terms of $\rho$ and $C_{\mu}$ fields as

$$\mathcal{L}= (\partial_{\mu}\rho)^{2}+\rho^{2}q^{2}C^{2}+\mu^{2}\rho^{2}-\lambda\rho^{4}-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} ,$$

where $C^{2}:=C^{\mu}C_{\mu}$.

Then he urges to break symmetry. (**What does it mean?** I can't understand this although I read his book section 26) The minima of the potential are on the circle at $\rho=\sqrt{\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\lambda}}$. And then he says that we choose the symmetry to be broken with $\rho_o=\sqrt{\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\lambda}}$ and $\theta_{0}=0$. I don't know what this sentence exactly means until now.

Anyway, next, he says that

"The expansion that reveals the excitations above the new ground state is most easily done by expanding in terms of a field $\chi$, defined as $\frac{\chi}{\sqrt{2}}:=\rho -\rho_0$. Ignoring constant terms we obtain :

$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\chi)^{2}-\mu^{2}\chi^{2}-\sqrt{\lambda}\mu\chi^{3}-\frac{\lambda}{4}\chi^{4} -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} +\frac{M^2}{2}C^2 + q^{2}(\frac{\mu^{2}}{\lambda})^{\frac{1}{2}}\chi C^{2} + \frac{1}{2}q^{2}\chi^{2}C^{2}+\cdots ,$

where $M:=q\sqrt{\frac{\mu^{2}}{\lambda}}$."

What does the paragraph "~by expanding in terms of a field $\chi$" exactly means? ( **Interlude question** : As he says, in the expansion, why can we ignore constant terms?) How can we perform an (Taylor) expansion of $\mathcal{L}$ to obtain the above series? I know the Taylor series of multi-variable, real-valued functions as in the wikipedia and I think that I am unfamiliar to the Taylor expansion of Lagrangian in terms of a field. I think understanding this example will be of great help in understanding his book section 26. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295807/why-does-the-scalar-field-have-the-wrong-sign-mass-term-in-its-lagrangian-to-spo?rq=1

This will be helpful for you. The $\frac{\chi}{\sqrt 2} = \rho - \rho_0$ is just new field which sets around the minima of $\rho$ to form new Lagrangian. 
Since the constant terms of Lagrangian is independent of  the  Euler-Lagrangian equation, they can be skipped

Comment: O.K, just the substitution $\rho = \frac{\chi}{\sqrt{2}}+ \rho_0$ with $\rho_0 := \sqrt{\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\lambda}}$ to the Lagrangian. Thank you!